# Connecting with arrows the data points of one variable, sorted by another variable

Tags: r

I have a dataframe similar to this [minimal example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fo7g41kw0epyvvh/arrows.csv?dl=0).

I am plotting Quality vs. Speed using ggplot.

```
ggplot(df_2,aes(x = Speed, y = Quality, k=GAME.ID) +
  geom_point(size=1) +
  labs(title="Quality vs. Speed")+
  theme_classic()-> plot
plot
ggplotly(plot)
```

I would like to connect with arrows the data points of each GAME.ID, sorted by interval. That is, one arrow from 0 to 1, another from 1 to 2, and so on up to 29 in each series.

I have been trying to use geom_curve and geom_segment but I dont know how I can connect several datapoints iteratively.

Comment: Can you give the output of your plot? Have you tried `geom_path()`?

Comment: Cheers, I had not tried geom_path. I am having a look at it at the moment. But not sure, so far, about how to make it work: geom_path(arrow=arrow(aes(group=x?)))

Comment: That's hard to concieve without data, but `geom_path(aes(x=GAME.ID), arrow = arrow(type = 'open'))` might work

Comment: Adding more info to good comments here. `c <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = Speed, y = Quality, color = as.factor(GAME.ID))); c + geom_line(arrow = arrow())` https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_path.html